# PdfLatex Compiling does not stop?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texstudio, windows

A few weeks ago , I started using Basic Miktex with TexMaker , everything was working fine (even tho compiling used to take minutes !) .
I uninstalled Basic Miktex and TexMaker and downloaded Complete Miktex then TexStudio , but now when I try to compile even the minimal latex code :
[image: Minimal Tex Code]

It says that compilation started but nothing happens no matter how much I wait , my pc starts heating in the process as if the compilation's crashing and doesn't stop until I force its abortion :
[image: Results]

My settings seem normal :
[image: Settings]

[image: Settings]

Any idea where the problem might be ?
(My pc is strong and fast , windows 10)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Yes, your settings look normal (almost: if you're under Windows, you should use SumatraPDF as an external pdfviewer, as Adobe Reader locks pdf files. What happens if you compile from the command line?

Comment: do you get a `.log` filre from the tex run, if so, what does it say?

Comment: The same thing happens when I compile from the command line : compilation does not stop .
I don't get a .log file .

Comment: @Bernard, DavidCarlisle , I'd be grateful if you gave the matter more attention.

Comment: Could you post a minimal code reproducing the problem? Aldo, from the command line, you have messages. Could you post them?

Comment: @Bernard , I did show a minimal code on top.
The command line only shows this (before the endless compilation starts) :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , I'd like to hear what you have to say about the problem .

Comment: I am not sure we can help at a distance, the error is not really a tex error but a problem with the pdftex executable on your machine, I guess you could try re-installing miktex, in any case the error is in teh miktex executable so any fix is likely to be miktex specific and I have never used miktex so can't really help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , are you recommending TexLive ? If so , what are the reasons ?

Comment: I don't just use windows (and even on windows I use the cygwin unix-like texlive) until very recently miktex was windows-only and I have been using texlive or its predecessor tetex or its predecessor unix-tex since 1987 or something so have never felt the need to try miktex

Comment: I'm gonna try reinstalling the distribution , i'll feed back once I get to see the results .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of the problem .

When I installed Complete MikTex , I did not **properly delete all** old Miktex files which probably triggered some compatibility issues resulting in an infinite loop when attempting to compile .